# How to configure duckdns.org on OpenWRT?

Tags: openwrt, dynamic-dns, ddns

I want to configure my OpenWRT router to update dynamic DNS once each day. I've chosen to use the free www.duckdns.org service. The duckdns service is not in the list of pre-configured services. How do I configure duckdns on OpenWRT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

duckdns.org has a very useful install page that generates all the information you need to copy/paste into your router GUI.

- logon to duckdns.org
- click on 'install' in the top menu bar
- enter your duckdns sub-domain in the bottom left of the page, where prompted
- click on the operating_system/router/standard you are interested in (such as OpenWRT or dd-wrt)
- the resulting screen will contain all the information you need for your situation. Just copy and paste into your gui, no edits needed!

Answer (score 2):

WRT, navigate to Setup->DDNS.
DNS Service: Custom
DYNDNS Server: duckdns.org
Username: <your duckdns account (probably email address)>
Password: 
Hostname: 
Url: [http://www.duckdns.org/update?domains=[USERNAME]&token=[PASSWORD]&ip=[IP]](http://www.duckdns.org/update?domains=%5BUSERNAME%5D&token=%5BPASSWORD%5D&ip=%5BIP%5D)

Answer (score 1):

Since OpenWRT doesn't list duckdns as a pre-configured dns provider, you'll have to create a custom entry.

1. In OpenWRT, navigate to Setup->DDNS.
2. DNS Service: `Custom`
3. DYNDNS Server: `duckdns.org`
4. Username: `<your duckdns account (probably email address)>`
5. Password: `<your duckdns token>`
6. Hostname: `<your duckdns sub-domain>`
7. Url: `http://www.duckdns.org/update?domains=[USERNAME]&token=[PASSWORD]&ip=[IP]`
8. Use external IP check: `yes`
9. Force Update Interval: `1`
10. Hit the `Save` and `Apply Settings` buttons.

Apply will cause the service to make a call to duckdns. The DDNS Status box will contain the results of the dynamic dns update request.